# How to Show Cartesian Sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to show that given:
\begin{align*}
P &= \{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}:  m \mid n\}, \\
Q &= \{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}:  n \mid m\}, \\
R &= \{(x,x) : x \in \mathbb{Z}\}, \\
\text{and } S &= \{(x, -x) : x \in \mathbb{Z}\}. 
\end{align*}

Show $P$ and $Q$ = $R$ or $S$

So, if $m|n$ and $n|m$, does this mean that $m=n$ and $m|n =n|m = 1$?

I don't really know where to go from there?

Comment: $m | n$ **iff** there exists some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $n= k \cdot m$. If both hold, then $k = { 1\over k}$ and there are not many elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ for which this holds.

Comment: if $(m,n)\in P\cap Q$ then $m=kn$ and $n=k'm$ for some integers $k,k'$ so $m=kn=kk'm$. If $m\neq 0$ then $kk'=1$ so either $k=k'=1$ or $k=k'=-1$. If $m=0$ then of course $n=0$

Comment: @copper.hat - I know it really only exists for 1, -1...but how do I show that for $R \cup S$? I feel like the second part, specifically $R \cup S$ is a much larger set than $P \cap Q$.

Comment: Prove it one step at a time. Pick $(m,n) \in P \cap Q$ and show the pair must be in either $R$ or $S$. Now pick an element of $R$ and show that it must be in $P \cap Q$ and repeat for an element of $S$. No emotions needed :-).

Comment: Thank-you, @copper.hat ...got it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = (m,n) \in P \cap Q$. Then $m|n$ and $n|m$ thus $n = \pm m$. Therefore $x \in R \cup S$. Thus $P\cap Q \subset R \cup S$.

Now let $x = (m,n) \in R \cup S$. You then have $m = \pm n$ thus $m|n$ and $m|n$ and therefore $x\in P \cap Q$. Therefore $R \cup S \subset P\cap Q$.

Therefore $P\cap Q = R\cup S$

Comment: Thank-you, I have combined the information from above with yours to make a very nice proof. Thanks again.